# Store each substring into different variables

Tags: java, string, substring

This is what I have

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hello, Ciao, Salut";
        String[] substring = input.split(", ");
        for (String s : substring) {
            System.out.println(s); // works
        }
    }
}
```

how can I assign each substring (`Hello`, `Ciao`, `Salut`) to a different variables?

E.g.

```
String english = // first substring, "Hello"
String italian = // second substring, "Ciao"
...
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with an array that you want to assign them to individual variables?

Comment: In all of the approaches using a hard-coded index to access the results of `split()`, you should definitely be checking the [length](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-length-or-size-of-an-array-in-java/) beforehand to make sure the input was at least as long as you were expecting...

Answer (score 0):

You can either split the input, or directly use `.substring()`.

**SPLITTING**

```
String input = "Hello, Ciao, Salut";
String[] split= input.split(", ");
String english = split[0];
String ciao= split[1];
String salut= split[2];
```

However, there is a bug - there will be an extra space in `ciao` and `salut`. You can mitigate this problem by directly using `.substring()`.

**SUBSTRING**

```
String english = input.substring(0,4);
String ciao = input.substring(7, 11);
String salut = input.substring(13);
```

Which produces:

```
Hello Ciao Salut
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can go with two approaches.

1. Declaration of variables
2. Declaration of List

**First Approach**
If we have to store each sub string in different variable, then we should know the the how many no of variable we need. so according we can declare and then initialize.
But in most of the cases, we don't know how many variables we need, so this approach we can't use in every case.

**Second Approach**
Here we can declare a list and add values in list and we can access using index or iterate list as well.

```
enter code here
String input = "Hello, Ciao, Salut";
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        String[] substring = input.split(", ");
        for (String s : substring) {
            list.add(s);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to declare and initiate the variable in your case is to use the array index and assign it to the variables in below way -

```
String english = substring[0];
String italian = substring[1];
```

There is other way where you can use the map and keep the map key as dynamic and corresponding value can be stored against it.
Eg -

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i=0;i<substring.length;i++) {
    map.put("language " + i, substring[i]);
}
```

The map (K -> V) will contain the values as -
language 1 -> Hello, language 2 -> Ciao, language 3 -> Salut

Answer (score -1):

What I did is

```
String english = substring[0];
String italian = substring[1];
...
```

is there another way?